# Having set up a Pi 4 to operate as a webserver over LAN, why isn't my pi 4 accessible over the internet after configuring port forwarding?

Tags: web-server

as the question states, I have successfully set up a **very** basic webserver using a raspberry pi 4 that I can successfully connect to in my LAN by just being on the same network and entering the private ip address of the pi4. However, what I need to do is make the pi 4 webserver accessible over the internet. Here are the steps I've followed and where I think I may be going wrong:

1. I have apache2 and mirianDB installed, under var/www/html/ I have for now just the default apache html page (although I have temporarily swapped with very basic html page and it works if I access the pi 4 ip address on the LAN). This is fine and can be accessed as expected
2. From what I understand, what I need to do next is go to the router page, and enable port forwarding which is where the problems begin I think. My ISP Hyperoptic do not allow port forwarding on port 80 as it is reserved by them. I have set up all ports, LAN and WAN side to be 8080.
   I have changed the ports to 0.0.0.0:8080 in the apache2.conf and ports.conf.
3. Now I find the public ip of my network using ipchicken.com which is 188.... etc.
4. Now, from outside my LAN (using my mobile phone cellular network) I attempt to access the webserver using the public ip address and then specify the port number, so it would be something like 188....:8080
   but nothing happens. It just attempts to load and then eventually times out.

I don't have a static ip but one can be purchased from the ISP. I will do this eventually, but for now I want to get it up and running for some very basic tests. I also don't yet care for any DNS stuff just yet. I have attempted multiple port configurations within the router itself, and I have attempted multiple apache2 port configurations/listening etc but it just wont work.

Is there anything obvious that I am doing wrong, or anything further that I can check? Any help would be greatly appreciated as I feel like I've attempted every solution.
running `netstat -tln` gives

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5900            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::5900                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

Comment: I'm noticing the output from your netstat shows the web server is only listening on port 80 of the IPv6 side but not the IPv4 side.  If you are forwarding to an IPv4 address, port 80 is not listening.  You may want to check your Apache configuration.

Comment: I didn't catch this, I'll try it now

Comment: I forced apache to use ipv4 in the config files and you can see that it seems to be listening on the appropriate port and protocol now. Unfortunately this hasn't solved my problem. If i use an online port forwarding tester, it still tells me that the port is closed

Comment: Because everything is working on the local network, the issue cannot be a problem of the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: @Ingo, this is my first time dealing with networking so there's quite a range of things to be learned. However, although Apache was listening on the correct port I wasn't sure if there could be something else causing an issue. Turns out my ISP uses a CGNAT so my public IP is shared anyway. I think that is probably the culprit

Answer (score 1):

You said you set the WAN port to 12000, but then tried to access 8080.

Try accessing [IP]:12000 which is the port number you've exposed to the internet.

Comment: This was a mistake on my part. The WAN port is set to 8080 not 12000. All ports are set to 8080. The problem seems to be that my ISP uses a CGNAT so I can't do port forwarding with ipv4 without buying a static IP from them. I'm now going to attempt to do the same thing but with ipv6.